# A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: esp32

so out of nowhere, my esp32 doesn't accept code to be uploaded on it (I do press the `BOOT` button on esp32 when uploading and it still fails to upload), I tried to upload code to another esp32 and it succeeded but I still can't understand what is the possible causes that cause my first esp32 not to accept code to be uploaded

[image]

edit : I tried to put a 10 micro Farad capacitor between EN pin and GND  and still nothing new